# How to center two labels vertically using autolauout

Tags: ios, autolayout

[image]

Please find attachment for more details.

Comment: It is easy to do.. did you try? What problems did you have? posting a title and an image is usually not enough for a good question

Comment: Thanks for comment. i am getting problem while setting top constraint with label 1. If it is so easy can you please help me to understand?

Comment: What you try to achieve, you say you have problems with the horizontal placement but you also refer to top constraint, which is for vertical placement :).

Comment: My mistake, updated question

Comment: Update your question mate, its unclear about what you want to achieve.

Comment: Set vertical constraint to center vertical, but change the value to ±25 or ±50 (according to the label), and same for the second one. Another solution is to use an intermediary view that will handles theses two labels, and center vertical that one.

Answer (score -1):

Use center horizontally constraints between two labels if you want vertical alignment.